# trouble installing Tkx perl module in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cpan, tkx

In order to install a package called PrimerMapper for designing primers on Ubuntu 14.04, I need to install a perl module called **Tkx** but facing trouble in installing it. So, kindly assist me in resolving this bug. 
For your quick and easy reference, I am pasting complete commands of installation. Thanks a lot

```
**adnan@adnan-Inspiron-N5110[Tkx-1.09]** sudo perl Makefile.PL            
Writing Makefile for Tkx
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

**adnan@adnan-Inspiron-N5110[Tkx-1.09]** sudo make                        
Skip blib/lib/Tkx/Tutorial.pod (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Tkx.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Tkx/MegaConfig.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Tkx/LabEntry.pm (unchanged)
cp tkx-prove blib/script/tkx-prove
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/tkx-prove
cp tkx-ed blib/script/tkx-ed
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/tkx-ed
Manifying blib/man1/tkx-ed.1p
Manifying blib/man3/Tkx::MegaConfig.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Tkx::LabEntry.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Tkx::Tutorial.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Tkx.3pm

**adnan@adnan-Inspiron-N5110[Tkx-1.09]** sudo make test                  
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/LabEntry.t ...... 1/2  (in cleanup) Can't call method "DeleteCommand" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Tcl.pm line 655 during global destruction.
t/LabEntry.t ...... ok   
t/mega-config.t ... ok   
t/mega.t .......... ok   
t/nul-char.t ...... ok   
t/tcl-callback.t .. 1/7  (in cleanup) Can't call method "DeleteCommand" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Tcl.pm line 655 during global destruction.
t/tcl-callback.t .. ok   
t/tcl.t ........... 1/18 # Test 18 got: "Tcl error 'Foo at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Tcl.pm line 585.\n' while invoking scalar result call:\n\t\"error Foo\" at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Tcl.pm line 588.\n\tTcl::call('Tcl=SCALAR(0x1b2ce48)', 'error', 'Foo') called at /media/windows/NGS/GATK_FINAL_PIPELINE/PrimerMapper-master/Tkx-1.09/blib/lib/Tkx.pm line 329\n\teval {...} called at /media/windows/NGS/GATK_FINAL_PIPELINE/PrimerMapper-master/Tkx-1.09/blib/lib/Tkx.pm line 329\n\tTkx::i::call('error', 'Foo') called at /media/windows/NGS/GATK_FINAL_PIPELINE/PrimerMapper-master/Tkx-1.09/blib/lib/Tkx.pm line 51\n\tTkx::AUTOLOAD('Foo') called at t/tcl.t line 38\n\teval {...} called at t/tcl.t line 38\n" (t/tcl.t at line 39)
#    Expected: "Foo at t/tcl.t line 38.\n"
#  t/tcl.t line 39 is: ok($@, "Foo at @{[__FILE__]} line @{[__LINE__ - 1]}.\n");
t/tcl.t ........... Failed 1/18 subtests 
t/tk.t ............ 12/12        (in cleanup) Can't call method "DeleteCommand" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Tcl.pm line 655 during global destruction.
t/tk.t ............ ok     
t/utf8.t .......... ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/tcl.t         (Wstat: 0 Tests: 18 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  18
Files=8, Tests=54,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.15 usr  0.03 sys +  1.85 cusr  0.31 csys =  2.34 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/8 test programs. 1/54 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  GAAS/Tkx-1.09.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GAAS/Tkx-1.09.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 GAAS/Tkx-1.09.tar.gz                         : make_test NO
```

Comment: Do you already have Tk installed?

Comment: Yes, TK is installed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the tests of the module don't pass successfully.

One thing I would try first is to try to install the module with `cpan` or `cpanminus` (`cpan Tkx` or `cpanm Tkx`). You (or the Makefile.PL) may have missed something that could be causing this error.

I see you already opened a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=115662) on CPAN. You can see in [cpantesters](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Tkx;perl=latest) that this module has the tests broken (you could check with your particular Perl version) and there is also another [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=67823) from 5 years ago reporting broken tests for the very same version that's currently on CPAN (1.09).

Considering this I think your options is to skip the tests and see if it works for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I recently adopted Tkx and published release 1.10, which allows installation to proceed despite the t/tcl.t test 18 failure.

The test failure appears to have been caused by unexpected but minor changes to error message formatting in newer Tcl.pm. Pending the issue actually being fixed, it is not something which Tkx should abort installation over.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a packaged version of Tkx for Ubuntu, so all it should take to get Tkx and any of its dependencies is:

```
sudo apt-get install libperl-tkx
```